# Ag Grid Enterprise Grouping

Tags: grouping, ag-grid, enterprise

I'm trying to figure out how AgGrid makes the request for new data when a group is expanded. I've seen this https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-enterprise-model/#enterprise-datasource in the docs but it doesn't give a great explanation as to how you setup the `dataSource` to receive the new data. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated: